# localstack ResourceNotFoundException and ResourceInUseException

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, localstack

There has been a lot of similar question related to localstack and dynamodb which are still unanswered.

I am trying to run local tests (tests written by dev team even the localstack configuration).

Whenever I am trying to run jest tests, there are two kinds of errors which I am seeing in the same suite, all the test suite that involves dynamodb only fails rests works.

- ResourceNotFoundException: Cannot do operations on a non-existent table
- ResourceInUseException: Cannot create preexisting table

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:0.9.4
    ports:
      - '4569:4569'
      - '4572:4572'
      - '4576:4576'
      - '4584:4584'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=dynamodb,s3,secretsmanager,sqs
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - DEFAULT_REGION=ap-northeast-1
```

**However the same configuration inside circle ci job works flawlessly. Why does it fail on my local, other devs are also facing the same issue.**

**Update :-** I tried to run this command `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4569 dynamodb list-tables` and it return `[]`

> I checked this too, but https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/5843 it didnt help, tried updating the localstack image tag but same errors

Feel free to ask for any other details, since i am new to docker and localstack ( if my question lacks important details)

Comment: could you provide a minimal reproducible example? also, be aware that localstack provides an aws CLI wrapper here: https://github.com/localstack/awscli-local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I was running test case with `jest` which results in parallel threads which alters the state of dynamodb after each state.

Runing `jest --runInBand` solves the issue as it results in single thread.